# how can I Highlight Ajax.ActionLink when is selected

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

So how can I Highlight when the client clicks  Ajax.ActionLink I have a class in CSS that works with @Html.ActionLink but for

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("select", "Index", "Certificacion",
                      new { id = item.CertificacionId },
                      new AjaxOptions
                      {
                          HttpMethod = "GET",
                          UpdateTargetId = "linkEdit",
                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                      },
         new { @class = "selectedRow" })|
```

so how can make that the client know was the selected

Comment: Could you also add the CSS class here?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what your css looks like

Comment: the css just do that

.selectedrow 
{ 
    background-color: #EEEEEE; 
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with JavaScript.  Here's an example using jQuery:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("select", "Index", "Certificacion", 
                      new { id = item.CertificacionId }, 
                      new AjaxOptions 
                      { 
                          HttpMethod = "GET", 
                          UpdateTargetId = "linkEdit", 
                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
                      }, 
         new { @class = "selectedRow", id = "YourActionLink" })
@* Notice the added html attribute property *@
```

Then your jQuery code could be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#YourActionLink').click(function()
        {
            $(this).addClass('YourSelectedItemClass');
        });
});
```

And then just some extremely simplified CSS just to complete this example:

```
.YourSelectedItemClass
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

### jQuery Working Example

Please see this [working jQuery jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Surfer/VV6ax/) to prove that the jQuery is correct.

Comment: @Diego_DX What exactly didn't work?  Did you get errors?  Could you not even run the code?  Did nothing just happen?

Comment: @Diego_DX are you sure you added the jQuery code to a script file that is included in the view that contains that ActionLink?  If the `*.js` file isn't in a `<script />` for that View (or a layout that the View uses), then nothing would happen.

Comment: yes, i put the code in the same view where the @Ajax.ActionLink is.

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#YourActionLink').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('selectedrow');
    });
</script>

Comment: @Diego_DX You also need the jQuery library referenced there, otherwise that code in your comment won't work.

Comment: @Diego_DX when you run this, look at the markup that is generated.  Verify that the `id` attribute of the `<a />` element is set to "YourActionLink".  If that is the case, then your jQuery isn't getting executed for some reason.

Comment: this was what the link generate is ok?

<a class="selectedRow" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#linkEdit" href="/Certificacion/Index/4" id="YourActionLink">Seleccionar</a>

Comment: @Diego_DX Yep, that markup looks good.  Check out my updated jQuery code in my answer.  Try that out.  The markup must not be rendered when that jQuery code executes.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Diego_DX Replace your jQuery code with `$(document).ready(function() { 
    alert('test');
});`.  I have a feeling that your jQuery code isn't even executing.  Let me know if that `alert()` does or doesn't occur.  (Node: this is just rudementary debugging)

Comment: @Diego_DX Take a look at my edit again (at the bottom of my answer above).  See that jsFiddle.  That's the exact code we're working with.  That proves that the jQuery code is working correctly.  In other words, for some reason your jQuery code is not executing it seems.

Comment: thank it work but just for my first row in mi list i will see why is that, thank you very much